# What is the base class exactly in this case?

Tags: c++, templates

What is the base class exactly in this case?

I have some difficulty to grab the full meaning of the first inheritance, due to the `FieldType::template` and `RecordPolicy<N>`

```
template<
class N,
    class FieldType
>
class FieldDefinition:
    public FieldType::template RecordPolicy<N>
{
public:
    typedef typename FieldType::GetSetPolicy::Type Type;
    typedef typename FieldType::GetSetPolicy::MemoryType MemoryType;
    typedef FieldType FieldClass;
};
```

Usage:

```
template<class ObjectClass_, class Schema_>
class Object:
    public virtual ObjectBase,
    public FieldDefinition<ObjectClass_, PointerField<ObjectClass_> >
{
    //...
}
```

Others:

```
template<class T> class PointerField;


template<class T>
class PointerField
{
    public:
    //...
    template<class N>
    class RecordPolicy : public SerializedField<N, PointerField<T> > {};
};
```

Comment: *One* of the base classes of `Object` is `FieldDefinition<ObjectClass_, PointerField<ObjectClass_>>`. The base class of `FieldDefinition<ObjectClass_, PointerField<ObjectClass_>>` is `PointerField<ObjectClass_>::RecordPolicy<ObjectClass_>`. And what that is we can't tell you since you don't show more.

Comment: I think the explanation of @Someprogrammerdude is enough, The full hierarchy is a nightmare, so not point of setting it here. The declaration of `PointerField` is supposed to have a typename `RecordPolicy` and that is what I was missing.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Feel free to write an answer if you want the score.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full hierarchy of `Object<Foo, Bar>` is:

```
Object<Foo, Bar>
  virtual ObjectBase
  FieldDefinition<Foo, PointerField<Foo>>
    PointerField<Foo>::RecordPolicy<Foo>
      SerializedField<Foo, PointerField<Foo>>
```

In particular, note that `FieldType::template RecordPolicy<N>` base clause. This means that `FieldDefinition` expects whatever class is supplied as `FieldType` (in your case, `PointerField<Foo>`) to have a *nested template* named `RecordPolicy` with a single type template parameter, for which `N` (in your case, `Foo` again) will be substituted. The class derives from the result of this instantiation, in your case the nested class `PointerField<Foo>::RecordPolicy<Foo>`, which in turn has another base class.

Comment: may I ask, what is the name of this construct `_classname_::template _classname<T>_` (more particular the ::template part)?

Comment: It's just a qualified-id with a nested-name-specifier using the `template` keyword for disambiguation. There is no particular name for this construct. The relevant parts of the current draft standard (N4687) are 8.1.4.2 for qualified names in general and 17.2 for the special case of template names.